# Cast WorkflowRun to run AbstractBuilder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to modify the workflow plugin for jenkins to start docker containers, and the plugin of docker to execute the action needs a parameter(AbastractBuild) that the workflow plugin does not provides but provides the "WorkflowRun" that it similar.

Answer (score 1):

[This document](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/basic-steps/CORE-STEPS.md#adding-support-from-plugins) has a bit of information, but in general you would need to find references to `AbstractBuild` and change them to `Run` (similarly `AbstractProject` to `Job`), and implement `SimpleBuildStep`. There may be other matching changes you would need to make, since some methods in `AbstractBuild` just do not make sense for a `WorkflowRun`. Use `jenkinsci-dev` for specific questions.